# How to send fast live input commands to android device using USB debugging?

Tags: android, adb

I want to configure some keys on my pc such that when they are pressed they trigger a specific touch input action on my android device.

Ex:- pressing K means touch input the centre of the screen and so on. Using the mouse to control the screen.

However, there are two problems which I can't solve:-

(1) adb shell is too slow to be used. It has delay of over a second because of the way it works by using java.

I need it to be as fast as possible.

(2) I can't find a way to send live touch input, most of the tools just record the gestures and perform them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in below steps

**Develop an app which runs as server and listens for your command on a port inside your device**

The app can be invoked from adb shell instrumentation command/service. Some code like below to receive the commands(strings) from your PC and do actions you need.

```
public void startServer() throws Exception {

    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
        CLIENT_SOCKET = serverSocket.accept();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                CLIENT_SOCKET.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        // Starting server
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            //out(inputLine);
            // do whatever with inputLine, handle touches for 'K'
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
           //err in connection, handle
    }
```

**forward your local port to port inside adb shell(that is your device port where the app listens)**

```
adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080
```

Above command forwards local PC port 8080 to 8080 port inside your adb shell device/emulator.

**A client(your PC) side program or script which connects, send commands to local port, which in turn reach the shell**

Example code in python

```
 import socket
 soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
 soc.connect(('127.0.0.1', 8080))
 soc.send('k\n') # this will reach inside the startServer function of app.
```

Above is just some example code, There will be lot of other `complete` examples for above steps online.

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing your app or simply using it via code, you can write most user interaction with your app using the [Android Testing tools](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/) like [Espresso](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso) or preferably [AndroidX testing](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/set-up-project) suite (bundled in Google's Jetpack).

The advantage of using a UI testing tool like Espresso would be its ability to wait for the uncertain duration between a user touch and its response by the device or emulator.

These tests are run the fastest possible on the device. You'll see the screen rapidly interacted with when you run the tests.

If you run these tests on an emulator it will be slow due to the inherent slow nature of emulators and their dependence on your system hardware. It'd be best if you run these on a device or on the cloud using [Firebase Test Lab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/).